# frontfill or backfill of STRING column at resample() in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-resample

is there any methode while doing resampling() to ffill() or bfill() a object column?

Suppose we have:

| Date | Sort | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-23 15:40:41 | A | 1 |
| 2022-10-23 18:43:13 | B | 2 |
| 2022-10-24 15:40:41 | C | 3 |
| 2022-10-24 18:43:13 | D | 4 |

i would like to have following results with:

```
df.resample("15min").mean()
```

| Date | Sort | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-23 15:45:00 | A | 1 |
| 2022-10-23 16:00:00 | A | 1 |
| 2022-10-23 16:15:00 | A | 1 |
| 2022-10-23 16:35:00 | A | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 2022-10-23 18:00:00 | D | 1 |
| 2022-10-23 18:15:00 | D | 1 |
| 2022-10-23 18:30:00 | D | 1 |
| 2022-10-23 18:45:00 | D | 1 |

but it always kick out the "sort column".
would be nice if anyone here can help!

best
M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need forward filling `first` valeus per `Sort` and `mean` per `Value` use:

```
df = df.resample("15min").agg({'Sort':'first', 'Value':'mean'}).ffill()
print (df)
                    Sort  Value
Date                           
2022-10-23 15:30:00    A    1.0
2022-10-23 15:45:00    A    1.0
2022-10-23 16:00:00    A    1.0
2022-10-23 16:15:00    A    1.0
2022-10-23 16:30:00    A    1.0
                 ...    ...
2022-10-24 17:30:00    C    3.0
2022-10-24 17:45:00    C    3.0
2022-10-24 18:00:00    C    3.0
2022-10-24 18:15:00    C    3.0
2022-10-24 18:30:00    D    4.0

[109 rows x 2 columns]
```